# Find the maximum number of people who participated in exactly three games?

Tags: combinatorics

> Gauri Apartment housing society organised annual games, 
>   consisting of three games: snooker, badminton and tennis. 
>   In all, $510$ people were members in the apartments' 
>   society and they were invited to participate in the games. 
>   Each person participating in as many games as he/she feels like. 
>   While viewing the statistics of the performance, Mr Capoor realised the following
>   facts. 
>   The number of people who participated in at least two games 
>   was $52$% more than those who participated in exactly one game.
>
> The number of people participating in $1$, $2$ or $3$ games respectively 
>   was at least equal to $1$.
>
> Being a numerically inclined person, he further noticed an interesting thing: 
>   The number of people who did not participate in any of the three games 
>   was the minimum possible integral value with these conditions.
>
> What was the maximum number of people who participated in exactly three games?

(a) $298$

(b) $300$

(c) $303$

(d) $304$

From the question I have drawn this venn diagram

[image]

and concluded that

$a+d+c+x=\dfrac{152\times (s+b+t)}{100} \\
\{s,b,t,a,d,c,x,\}\geq 1$

I don't know how to proceed.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: I have converted the image stating the problem to text, hoping that it would be more readable. Please confirm accurate translation and remove the picture if you so see.

Comment: The sentence "The number of people who did not participate in any of the three games was the minimum possible integral value with these conditions." is ambiguous.

Comment: If we mark $u := a+b+c$ we get equation: $u+x = 1.52*(510-x-u) $ which hasn't solution in whole numbers.

Comment: I think the condition "at least one person participated in two games"  translates to at least one of $a,b,c$ being greater than zero, not all.

Comment: Further, why is letter $b$ used (in the diagram and the equations) for two different things? Some typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P=N_2+N_3$ count those who participated in at least two games, $Q=N_1$, those who participated in one game.

Then $$P=\frac{152}{100}Q \implies \frac{P}{Q}=\frac{38}{25}$$ Or $(P,Q)=(k\,38,k\,25)$.
The total number of players who played at least one game is $P+Q=k(38+25)=k\, 63$ (hence $k \,63\le 510$). We are told the players that didn't played is minimized, hence $P+Q$ is maximized.  The maximum $k$ is 8. And $P+Q=8 \times 63 = 504$, and $(P,Q)=(304,200)$

Now, $P=N_2+N_3=304$ We have the restriction that at least one person participated in exactly two games, i.e. $N_2 \ge 1$. Then the maximum value of $N_3$ is $304-1=303$